# Are there infinitely many solutions to this equation involving primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider this equation where $p$ are primes:

$$(p_k)^2+(p_{k+1})^2-1=(p_{k+2})^2$$

A possible solution is given by $p_k=7$, $p_{k+1}=11$ and $p_{k+2}=13$.
Do you believe that there are infinitely many solutions?
Or plenty of solutions?

Comment: @Peter do you want to find other solutions?

Comment: Since you are looking for consecutive primes, there will definitely be only finitely many solutions. This is because for larger values of $k$, note that $p_k$, $p_{k+1}$ and $p_{k+2}$ will all be fairly close to each other. Thus, the LHS would become close to $2p_k^2$ and the RHS would be close to $p_k^2$. A program to check up to some reasonable size prime, e.g., even a few thousand should be enough, would give you all the solutions. A more interesting problem is if the primes involved could be any primes at all.

Comment: $(11,13,17)$ is the next, and as @JohnOmielan indicates, likely last, solution.

Comment: can be rewriiten in terms of prime gaps.

Comment: $23^2+29^2-1=37^2,$ but $31$ is a prime

Comment: $(p_k-1)(p_k+1)=(p_{k+2}-p_{k+1})^2+(2p_{k+1})(p_{k+2}-p_{k+1}) $  prime gap of the latter 2 ( or twice it in the case of all odd primes) , needs be a factor of the first plus or minus 1 .

Comment: parforprime(x=3,1000,2*(nextprime(nextprime(x+1)+1)-nextprime(x+1)),j,if(gcd(x+1,j)==j || gcd(x-1,j)==j, print(x","nextprime(x+1)","nextprime(nextprime(x+1)+1))))

Comment: Upto $10^8$ , no further solution. I agree FredH's conjecture that there are only two solutions.